# POST form not writing to Django database

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I'm having some trouble getting data from an html form to write new stuff to the sqlite database.  I've used something similar to edit existing entries (contacts) originally created via shell but it doesn't seem to work when creating new entries.  When I submit the form, it shows the same page, but blank, and doesn't redirect me either.

My HTML:

```
<form action="{% url 'contactmanager:addnewcontact' %}" method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
<ul>
    <li><label>First Name: </label> <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname"/></li>
    <li><label>Last Name: </label> <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname"/></li>
    <li><label>Email: </label> <input type="text" name="email" id="email"/></li>
    <li><label>Phone Number: </label> <input type="text" name="pnumber" id="pnumber"/></li>
    <li><label>Notes: </label> <input type="text" name="notes" id="notes"/></li>
</ul>
<input type="submit" value="Create" />
</form>
```

My view.py:

```
def addnewcontact(request):
    contact = ContactList(fname=request.POST.get('fname'), lname=request.POST.get('lname'))
    contact.save()
    contactinfo = ContactList.objects.get(pk=contact.id)
    contactinfo.contactdetails_set.create(lname=request.POST.get('lname'), email=request.POST.get('email'), pnumber=request.POST.get('pnumber'), notes=request.POST.get('notes'))
    return HttpResponseRedirect('contactmanager/index.html')
```

My models.py:

```
class ContactList(models.Model):
    fname = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    lname = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    def __str__(self):
        contact_name = self.fname + ' ' + self.lname
        return contact_name
class ContactDetails(models.Model):
    fname = models.ForeignKey(ContactList, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    lname = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pnumber = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    notes = models.TextField(default = ' ')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

FYI: fname is the foreign key that relates the ContactDetails model to ContactList.

Is there something wrong with my ORM queries?  They're similar to the ones I used to create some initial 'contacts' via python manage.py shell.

Comment: Really, you should use the Django forms framework here.

Comment: I will in future for sure; I've learnt my lesson.  But as far as this project goes, this is the last hurdle so I'm just going to roll with it for now.

Comment: Can you post your models? And is `contactmanager/index.html` the empty form?

Comment: Done.  index.html just loops through the contacts in the ContactList model and displays them.  So I'm expecting that the newly created ones would show up there.